# What is the best way to paginate results in hql

Tags: sql, performance, grails, pagination, hql

I want to paginate results in grails application. For querying, I am using hql. The query works as following.

```
List response= Order.executeQuery(selectQuery + queryWhere, [offset:command.offset, max:command.max])
```

However only showing filtered values are not enough. I have to show how many results the query is bringing without filtering as well. At the moment

```
def count=Order.executeQuery("select count(*)" + queryWhere)
```

For the efficiency, I am wondering if it is possible to make some kind of trick and call query only once? Because basically, I am calling the same query twice. I am looking for the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest to use createCriteria method to search for records in the database using the criteria API. Here is sample e.g:

```
 def orderListCriteria = Order.createCriteria()
    def list = orderListCriteria.list(max:max,offset:offset) {
                eq("user",user)
                eq("",)   //actual filter query
                order(,)
            }
   def count = list.totalCount // this will give total count
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I need a solution in sql or hql. Regards,

Comment: How can this be achieved with HQL?